# i am facing LNK2019 error uresolved external error

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I am creating a text compression using huffman algorithm .
In this I want to create a Huffman Tree , CreateHMNode accept two nodes and create a node with sum of frequency of others .

but it shows this error ,please help me to solve

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl HMnode::HMnode(void)" (??0HMnode@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl HMtree::build_tree(class HMnode *,class HMnode *)" (?build_tree@HMtree@@QEAAXPEAVHMnode@@0@Z)

```
void  build_tree(HMnode* temp3, HMnode* temp13)
{

    HMnode* head1;

    HMnode* newnode = new HMnode;
    newnode = createHMNode(temp3, temp13);
    head1 = newnode;
    HMnode* mytemp = calldeque();
    createHMNode(newnode, mytemp);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HMnode::HMnode(void)` mentioned in the error message is the `HMnode` default constructor.

When you do `new HMnode` you default-construct a `HMnode` object, and it needs the default constructor.

If, for some reason, you don't have a default constructor you will get an error about it. Normally you would get a compiler (not link) error, which means there's a *declaration* of the `HMnode` default constructor, but there's no *definition* (implementation).

Either you don't link with all object files or libraries, or you forgot to define (implement) the default constructor in your code.

Comment: Thankyou soo much it is solved . error is in default constructor {} are missing that's why this error is coming ,bundle of thanks

Comment: @RehanAkhtar If you don't have any code or other specific initialization in your default constructor, mark it as "defaulted", like `HMnode() = default;` Then the compiler will create a suitable constructor for you.